# Start mongo from Windows command file

Tags: mongodb, cmd

I created a command (start.cmd) file with the following contents:

```
c:\pymon\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath c:\pymon\mongodb\data
```

But all it does is open a new blank command shell.

I then tried:

```
cmd /c c:\pymon\mongodb\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath c:\pymon\mongodb\data
```

But that does the same thing.

All I want is to start mongo using my own database path without having to specify the dbpath. I thought it could be done with a configuration file, but reading the documentation you've got to supply a parameter to mongod.exe to use the config file meaning my above cmd file still wouldn't work.

What am I doing wrong? any other program starts fine using the above.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using a batch file (.bat) ?

Comment: Do you have the directory c:\pymon\mongodb\data created and with the correct access ? Did you try just running the command from command line ? What do you get ?

Answer (score 7):

Please follow these simple steps to create a bat file, Which will run your mongo-server just on the click of this bat file. Instead of we manually configuring the path each time while starting the server.

- **Step 1:** Create a empty bat file on your desktop, Name it as *startmongoserver.bat* 
  [image]
- **Step 2:** Right click on this bat file, Edit (with notepad) and then paste this code `start call "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath /Users/tsabu/Mongodb-data` 
  [image]
  Note : In above example `/Users/tsabu/Mongodb-data` is the path to your folder which store all your mongodb data. To generalize this path `/Users/(admin or user-name)/(folder-name)`
  [image]
- **Step 3:** Save this *startmongoserver.bat* file , close the notepad (editor) and then run this (.bat) file.

Answer (score 2):

create a batch file ...bat with

```
start call "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe"
start call "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongo.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward way is to create config file mongod.cfg that contains like below:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
  dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\data\db
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  port: 27017
```

then run this command in the bin folder inside mongodb:

```
mongod --config mongod.cfg
```

If you want to install as MongoDB service you should run like this, be sure to write  absolute path for mongod.cfg:

```
mongod --config "C:\ProgramFiles\MognoDB\Server\...\bin\mongod.cfg" --install
```

If you don't mention absolute path in the command or inside config file when you want to install as windows service, it will give error.
Then you can start MongoDB service with:

```
net start MongoDB
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>In both the approaches, you are spinning off a shell that starts the mongod process and exits.</strike> Have you considered using Mongodb as a windows service?

The `--install` option of `mongod.exe` can help you set it up. Refer [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/program/mongod.exe/)

Edit: Actually, what I said above isn't true. I could get a cmd file to work.

**start.cmd**

```
"c:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath c:\mongodbdata\temp
```

Comment: What is the contents of your cmd file then?

Comment: Sorry - hit save too soon.

Comment: thanks for your help, it made me realise in a roundabout way what I did wrong. see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you run my command from File explorer it works fine, but from a command line it has the problem I created.

So, from a command line you can do:

```
cmd /c start.cmd
```

and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with bat extension, right click and edit the file, paste mongo installation path. For me as windows user

```
start call "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin\mongod.exe"
```

Double click on bat file with run the mongo